# Changing labels language in LibreOffice

Tags: language, libreoffice-writer

I'm using the Italian version of LibreOffice 4.0.4, and writing a document in English. I set English as document language, and the spellchecking works properly.

However, when I insert captions and cross references, the labels are in italian. For example *Tabella* instead of *Table*.

What should I change in order to have the proper labeling, besides installing an English version of LibreOffice Writer??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although this doesn't solve the bug itself, I found a workaround by creating custom labels with the name of the label in the desired language. Once labeled an item (say an image), every time the same kind of item is inserted the custom caption is selected by default.

In my case, I've created a lable called "Figure" and one called "Table" (my LibreOffice is in Italian).

Also, saving the template should make the custom labels available when used.